# Find Fourier Transform of $\cos^2(ωt)x(t)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, signal-processing

I have
$x(t)=
\begin{cases}
    2,& 0 < t < 2 \\
    1,& 2 < t < 3 \\
    0,&\text{elsewhere} \\
\end{cases},\ $
and I'm trying find the Fourier fransform of
$y(t) = \cos^2(ωt)x(t)$

**What I have done:**

I have proceeded solving it using the definition of the Fourier Transform, but I would like to believe there is an easier way to find the result.

$
\begin{align}
Y(f)
& = 2\int_0^2 cos^2(ωt)e^{-jωt}dt + \int_2^3 cos^2(ωt)e^{-jωt}dt\\
& = 2\int_0^2 \left({1\over2} +  {1\over2}cos(2ωt)\right)e^{-jωt}dt
  + \int_2^3 \left({1\over2} +  {1\over2}cos(2ωt)\right)e^{-jωt}dt\\
& = \int_0^2 e^{-jωt}dt + \int_0^2 cos(2ωt)e^{-jωt}dt
  + {1\over2}\int_2^3 e^{-jωt}dt + {1\over2}\int_2^3 cos(2ωt)e^{-jωt}dt\\
& = \left[{{e^{-jωt}}\over{-jω}}\right]_0^2
  + \int_0^2 \left({{e^{j2ωt} + e^{-j2ωt}}\over{2}}\right)e^{-jωt}dt
  + {1\over2}\left[{{e^{-jωt}}\over{-jω}}\right]_2^3
  + {1\over2}\int_2^3 \left({{e^{j2ωt} + e^{-j2ωt}}\over{2}}\right)e^{-jωt}dt\\
& = {{1 - e^{-j2ω}}\over{jω}}
  + {1\over2}\int_0^2 e^{jωt} + e^{-j3ωt}dt
  + {{e^{-j2ω} - e^{-j3ω}}\over{j2ω}}
  + {1\over4}\int_2^3 e^{jωt} + e^{-j3ωt}dt\\
& = {{1 - e^{-j2ω}}\over{jω}}
  + {{e^{j2ω} - 1}\over{j2ω}}
  + {{1 - e^{-j6ω}}\over{j6ω}}
  + {{e^{-j2ω} - e^{-j3ω}}\over{j2ω}}
  + {{e^{j3ω} - e^{j2ω}}\over{j4ω}}
   + {{e^{-j6ω} - e^{-j9ω}}\over{j12ω}}
\end{align}
$

I'm using $ω = 2πf$ to preserve space.

**Question:**

The function $x(t)$ is evidently a sum of rectangular pulses:
$x(t) = 2rect\left({{t - 1}\over2}\right) + rect\left(t - {5\over2}\right)$.
Is there a way to take advantage of the properties of Fourier Transform to find $Y(f)$ quickly without so much writing action?

Comment: Is the $\omega$ in $\cos^2(\omega t)$ different, or the same as the $\omega$ in the Fourier transform?

Comment: The same $ω = 2πf$.

Comment: Then that doesn't make sense to me, because it makes it no longer a Fourier transform if the function has both $\omega$ and $t$. If that $\omega$ is just a constant, like $\omega_0$. then you'll have something

Comment: What I want to find $Y(f)$. I just changed $2πf$ to $ω$ to preserve space @Dylan. I guess I've accidentally corrupted the post; my bad. Consider $ω=2πf$ everywhere, except $Y(ω)$ which is $Y(f)$.

Comment: This still wouldn't change if you just switch out $\omega = 2\pi f$ everywhere. We need the parameter and the transform variable to be different

Comment: Yes, you are right @Dylan. In an attempt to make the code fit well in the post I tried to preserve space without taking into consideration that changing the variables will alter the meaning of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume the modulation function is $$ f(t) = \cos^2(2\pi f_0 t) = \frac12 + \frac12 \cos (4\pi f_0 t) = \frac12 + \frac14 e^{j4\pi f_0 t} + \frac14 e^{-j4\pi f_0 t} $$

of which the Fourier transform is
$$ F(f) = \frac12 \delta (f) + \frac14 \delta (f - 2f_0) + \frac14 \delta (f + 2f_0)$$

Then the transform of a product is a convolution

$$ \mathcal{F}\{f(t)x(t)\} = F(f) * X(f) = \frac12 X(f) + \frac14 X(f - 2f_0) + \frac14 X(f + 2f_0) $$

where $X(f)$ is the Fourier transform of $x(t)$. Since you have already expressed $x(t)$ as the sum of two $\operatorname{rect}$ functions, this is easily the sum of two (frequency-shifted) $\operatorname{sinc}$ functions

Comment: Thanks for the help @Dylan. I'm little confused, because I'm used to working with $Y(f)$ rather than $Y(ω)$, but I think I can take it from here.

Comment: The formulas are no different between $\omega$ and $f$. Personally I'm also more familiar with the $2\pi f$ transform

Comment: But $f_0 \ne 2f $